# smart_listing custom sort rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, smart-listing

i have this code

`%th= smart_listing.sortable(t('.name'), 'name')`

Suppose the name is divided into two parts, first and last name (example: "Carlos Gonzales"), is there any way to sort by the last name?

Comment: How would you sort names that contain 3 or 4 parts? If there are 3 parts how do you know if the second part is a second first name or the first last name? I am afraid you cannot automatically sort by last name unless you have a dedicated last name column in your database. And if you have a dedicated last name column you still need to be able to handle people without a lasz name (yes that is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it always contains only two parts yes it is possible. You can use `sort_by` method which accepts block of code. Example:

```
full_names.sort_by {|full_name| full_name.split[1]}
```

But it's not general solution. As spicermann commented if You have more complicated names it is very difficult to handle that. I found this [gem](https://github.com/basecamp/name_of_person) but it's not also general solution.

Comment: Thanks! could you comment what the implementation would be like using this gem?

Comment: in which part should I put the code you sent?

Comment: You should use it on Your Array with names